# titlesec package not suppressing chapter number from section in XeLaTex

Tags: xetex, titlesec, section-titles

Am using the **Overleaf** online editor, and in order to use the `polyglossia` for Arabic fonts support package, I changed the compiler to **XeLaTex**. everything worked as expected, except for the `titlesec` package.

I was using `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` to remove the chapter number from the section numbering, but after the change, it didn't work.

I faced the same issue with `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}` and `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}`.

is there a way to fix this while still using **XeLatex**? because I need the Arabic support provided by it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe try adding `\counterwithin*{section}{chapter}`

Comment: It is better to add a minimal working example (MWE) which shows us the issue.

Comment: @SalimBou I am new to this, thanks for the tip though, I'll make sure to do so the next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `bidi.sty` which is loaded by `polyglossia` if you use any R-L languages. In the name of trying to properly format various structures in the document for R-L typesetting, it has a large amount of hardcoded overrides of different document class settings. You don't specify your document class, but it does things to most of the common document classes (I encountered this issue when I wanted to add a short example of some Hebrew text in my LaTeX book and had `bidi` overwrite the formatting that I had set up for figure and table captions).

It *should* be enough to put your `\renewcommand` statements *after* `\usepackage{polyglossia}` and its associated language declarations. I did a quick test to verify this, but I don't know what else you have in your document so I can't guarantee it.

Comment: Thank you! it worked perfectly, i placed the ```\renewcomman``` after ```\usepackage{polyglossia}``` and it worked for both sections and figures.